# Get all items in the compare list and filter them by visitor_id?

Tags: collection, magento-1, products, compare

I want to get all items from the product compare list, but only for a certain visitor. This is what I tried:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();
$test = $_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('visitor_id', 2)->getItems();
```

This should return nothing, because in my catalog_compare_item table is no row for visitor_id 2. But it returns everything no matter if I use a filter or not. Whats the correct way of doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: comment out the `->getItems()` part and complete your code with:
`$_productCollection->count();
echo $_productCollection->getSelect()->__toString();`
and see what's happening in the SQL query, it might lead you to the solution

Comment: I debugged and got the SQL. When I run it in my SQL editor, it returns nothing (which is right), but the code still has 1 result (checked with count). What could be the reason?

Comment: so when you run the SQL by itself, it gives you no result, at all ? and when you echo the `$_productCollection->count()` it gives you 1?
That is some weird stuff. What is you loop through the `getItems()` ? Is there something out of the ordinary in what it gives you?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the SQL seems to be right, the code not. Looping through the collection gives me the one product for visitor_id 1, which is not what I expect when I pass 2 to addFieldToFilter. This is my code now:

`$collection = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('visitor_id', 2);
$sql = $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
$count = $collection->count();
foreach($collection as $product) {
    $id = $product->getId(); // thats the id from the product with visitor_id 1
}
`

Comment: I tried using getSize() instead of count() and it returns either 0 or 1, which is correct. But still, the foreach iterates one time, which is wrong.

Comment: Solved it by using $collection->getData() in the foreach!

Comment: Glad you solved this.

Comment: @user1638055 feel free to add you own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Not completely sure what you are wanting to do but the following should work well to loop through the items.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();
foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName();
}
```

You can note that the `Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection()` will already add a filter for the visitor/customer so you should not have to add this filter.

If you are wanting to loop through another user's items that I would suggest not using this function but simply building your own collection from:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_compare_item_collection')
    ->useProductItem(true)
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```